# How to get the start and the end of date for each month with NaiveDate (Rust)?

Tags: rust

How to get the last date of a month with `chrono::NaiveDate`. I try to search the manual but can't found anything useful.

```
   use chrono::{NaiveDate, Datelike};

   // from January to December m = 1 - 12
   for m in 1..=12 {
        let end = ..... ?? 
        let start_date = NaiveDate::from_ymd(year, m, 1);  /// each month starts with 1
        let end_date = NaiveDate::from_ymd(year, m, end); /// here's the problem
        container.push((start_date, end_date));
   }
```

the closest would be to use `Datelike::day` https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.6/chrono/trait.Datelike.html#tymethod.day0
and subtract 1 day from it, but I don't know how to do that with `NaiveDate`. I'm open to any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pred()`or `pre_opt()`.

A very dirty solution that works like this

```
for m in 1..=12 {
        let start_date = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2022, m, 1);
        
        let mut end_date;
        if m < 12 {
            end_date = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2022, m + 1, 1).pred();    
        } else {
            end_date = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2023, 1, 1).pred();    
        }

        println!("{:?}", end_date);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

## Proposal for requested function

The function `last_day_of_month` already was proposed to be added to the chrono library on GitHub, but was not accepted.

## The Code

The following solution works exactly like @Zeppi's solution, but uses a more *rusty* approach.
An `Option<NativeDate>` returned from `NativeDate::from_ymd_opt` is used to check whether the month is the 12. month to the switch to the edge-case, where the day is the last day of the month.

```rust
fn last_day_of_month(year: i32, month: u32) -> NaiveDate {
    NaiveDate::from_ymd_opt(year, month + 1, 1)
        .unwrap_or(NaiveDate::from_ymd(year + 1, 1, 1))
        .pred()
}
```

<sup>*Credits to @lifthrasiir on GitHub for the code*</sup>

### Sources

[Chrono library Issue 69: Provide `days_in_month()`](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/69)

[Chrono library Issue 29: Leap year and last day of month](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/29)